# resizable div width outline in firefox

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, firefox

Outline position becomes wrong if I applay resizable function on a div.

The ui-resizable-handle-s (shown gray in demo) expands the outline (red) though their positions are set to absolute.

How can I fix it? The problem appears only in FF.

Take a look at the [demo](http://jsbin.com/ekokex/1/edit).

Comment: I had this problem too and found it works better if you use a border instead of an outline then use `margin-top: -1px;` and `margin-left: -1px;` if you need to fix the position (change 1 to width of border).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.ui-resizable-s {
    cursor: s-resize;
    height: 7px;
    width: 100 % ;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: 0;
}
```

This css rule binds the `ui-resizable-s` size to its parent size.

```
width:100%
bottom:-5px;
left:0;
```

These 3 mean:

- Have the full width of the parent
- Top edge stays `5px` bellow the parents bottom edge on y-axis
- Left edge stay on `0` from parents left edge on x-axis

With those 3 together it will always fallow parent on resizeing and moreover they do work exactly beacause `position` is `absolute`

Comment: So I need add another container div that has outline: http://jsbin.com/ekokex/5/edit

Comment: Yep, you can do that or since your `cont` div is positioned `relative`  you can do that, too: `.outline{top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;}`